# Python URL Stepping Returns Only First Page Results

Tags: python, python-2.7

Any help with the below code would be appreciated. I have checked the results of h and g using print to verify that they are incrementing the url properly, but the program seems to be only repeating the results from first page. Hope this makes sense and I have provided enough info. I know this code looks terrible.

edit** I am testing the code as I go in the Python2.7 shell. I have it print the link results to make sure they are working correctly, but it just repeats pg1.

Update** The problem with the code was due to the website using json to get pages. 
[Python Link to File Iterator not Iterating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20568743/python-link-to-file-iterator-not-iterating)

```
g = 'http://www.somesite.com/pg'
b = 'http://www.somesite.com/pg'
PageCount = 1

while PageCount < 3:
    h = g + str(PageCount)
    c = b + str(PageCount)

    f = urllib2.urlopen(h)

    # variable a is for the second function that opens links for webpages
    # meeting criteria from variable f
    a = urllib2.urlopen(c)

    # res variable captures lines for items meeting criteria to be opened in a webpage
    res = []

    PageCount += 1        

    #check function checks for criteria current webpage
    check()

    #ReturnLine function opens webpages using data from variable res
    ReturnLine()
```

Comment: Have you printed `h` to see if you might have a problem with `urlopen`, i.e. have the correct url, but another problem? The code (especially the increment of `PageCount`) looks fine to me. Can you add the output you are observing? Are you sure, the url is correct?

Comment: Yep. Commented out `check()` and `ReturnLine` and added `print h` and `print c`. both return incremented results.

Comment: Then I assume that there exists some problem in the url-forming. Try accessing the urls directly using your browser. Are they actually different?

Comment: No problem with the links. The whole link is always the same with the page number on the end. I copied the results from the Python shell and pasted them in the web browser and they open just fine. PG one results open just fine. ... they just open twice.

Comment: Wait.. PG opens every page twice? I thought, that it would always open the same page, nomatter which number you add. Please clarify your question in this regard.

Comment: Sorry let me clarify. With `PageCount` I'm only checking the results from criteria on the first two pages. it should be opening aroung 20 webpages in all, but it just opens criteria from the first page twice.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42995/discussion-between-pystarter-and-timmay)

Answer (score 0):

I derived a minimal working example (no lengthy code possible in comment section..)

```
g = 'http://www.somesite.com/pg'
PageCount = 1

while PageCount < 3:
    h = g + str(PageCount)

    print h

    PageCount += 1
```

which is working just fine. The output is

```
http://www.somesite.com/pg1
http://www.somesite.com/pg2
```

Is this what you get? If so, try calling urllib2.urlopen([URL]) with a fixed url to check proper function in a *separate* minimal working example and go from there. Otherwise I see no error (or sources of error) that may cause such a behaviour.

Comment: That code works the same as mine. I think it either has something to do with the looping or trying to change the variable that is appended to the link that is causing it to only to return results from the first page. Sorry I wasn't available for chat I was driving home.