# Python Link to File Iterator not Iterating

Tags: python, loops, python-2.7, urllib2

This one has had me stumped for a couple of days now and I believe I've finally narrowed it down to this block of code. If anyone can tell me how to fix this, and why it is happening it would be awesome.

```
import urllib2

GetLink = 'http://somesite.com/search?q=datadata#page'
holder = range(1,3)

for LinkIncrement in holder:
    h = GetLink + str(LinkIncrement)
    ReadLink = urllib2.urlopen(h)
    f = open('test.txt', 'w')

    for line in ReadLink:
        f.write(line)  

    f.close()
    main() #calls function main that does stuff with the file
    continue
```

The problem is it will only write the data from `'http://somesite.com/search?q=datadata#page'` if I do the below the results print correctly.

```
for LinkIncrement in holder:
    h = GetLink + str(LinkIncrement)
    print h
```

The link I am copying does indeed increment in this manner and I am able to open the urls by copying and pasting. Additionally, I have tried this with a `while` loop, but always get the same results.

The below code opens 3 tabs with the incremented urls `/search?q=datadata#page1`, `/search?q=datadata#page2`, and `/search?q=datadata#page3`. Just can't make it work in my code.

```
import webbrowser
import urllib2
h = ''
def tab(passed):
    url = passed
    webbrowser.open_new_tab(url + '/')

def test():

    g = 'http://somesite.com/search?q=datadata#page'
    f = urllib2.urlopen(g)      
    NewVar = 1
    PageCount = 1

    while PageCount < 4:

            h = g + str(NewVar)                  
            PageCount += 1
            NewVar += 1
            tab(h)
test()
```

Thanks to Falsetru for helping me figure this out. The website was using json for any pages after the first page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the url, the part after `#` ([fragment identifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier)) is not passed to web server; Server respond with same content because parts before framents identifier are same.

`#something` is handled by browser (javascript). You need to see what happens in javascript.

Comment: I think this might also be the answer to the OP's [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20530457/python-url-stepping-returns-only-first-page-results) as long as this time we're sure there is actually a `#`... If so, I expect we know what the next question is going to be... :)

Comment: And the file `test.txt` is overwritten in each loop which might or might not be what the OP wants.

Comment: I thought you may have nailed it, but I just updated my question with code that does what I need it to do. Just couldn't get it to work when I put it in my code. @Matthias, I do not care about retaining each link in text form.

Comment: @Timmay, See javascript code included in the page. Or Maybe investigate network information provided by your browser debug facility will be easier.

Comment: What would I be looking for in the JS code? Would those still possibly be a problem if I am able to open the links with code at the bottom of my question? JS code does show that base URI is everything before fragment identifier.

Comment: @Timmay, Without seeing the actual page, I can't answer. Try to see network information from {Firebug, Developer Tools, ...}.

Comment: I looked at network information in Chrome but didn't really see anything that stood out. here is the page I am attempting to increment. http://steamcommunity.com/market/search?q=appid%3A570+common

Comment: @Timmay, The second page is accessed through `http://steamcommunity.com/market/search/render/?query=appid%3A570%20common&search_descriptions=0&start=10&count=10`. The thrid page is `http://steamcommunity.com/market/search/render/?query=appid%3A570%20common&search_descriptions=0&start=20&count=10` ... Found this information from network tab of Developer Tools (Chrome). URL in the location is not actual URL passed to server as I answered.

Comment: @Timmay, Above url returns `json` response, not `html`. Browser (javascript) parse it and render to screen. Actually parsing `json` is alot easier than `html` ;)

Comment: @Timmay, Use `'http://steamcommunity.com/market/search/render/?query=appid%3A570%20common&search_descriptions=0&start={}&count=10'` as url format string. Fetch it and parse using `json.load` or `json.loads`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43144/discussion-between-timmay-and-falsetru)